# How to monitor projection creation process in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Materializing a projection takes time. How I can monitor it after materializing?

```
ALTER TABLE actions ADD PROJECTION by_month (...)

ALTER TABLE actions MATERIALIZE PROJECTION by_month
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `actions` is the name of the table:

```
select * from system.mutations where table = 'actions' AND NOT is_done
```

`parts_to_do` column indicates number of parts to be mutated until projections finishes materializing.